# SQL Server : select when at least one mach from each option

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select from `Property` when at least 1 for each `Pid` is exists in `UserData`

**Property**:

```
Pid  OptId
----------
5     12 
5     13
5     14
6     22
6     23
7     28
7     29
```

**UserData**:

```
UId Pid OptId
---------- 
1   5   13
1   6   23
1   7   28
2   5   12
2   6   22
```

The results should be:

```
UId Pid OptId
------------- 
1   5   13
1   6   23
1   7   28
```

The results shows only the rows for `Uid=1` because it has at least one `Pid` for each property (5,6,7). `Uid=2` does not include in result because it has `pid = 5 & 6` but does not have `Pid=7`

Is it possible?

Comment: It is not clear why you are choosing to show `Uid=1` as opposed to `Uid=2`.

Comment: uId=2 does not have Pid=7 from Property

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: Can you post your Query ??

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/HYVAS23452)**

First you need to know how many properties are

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Pid) as total_properties
 FROM Property
```

Then you need to see how many properties has each `UserData`

```
SELECT u.UId, count(DISTINCT u.Pid) as Uid_property
FROM UserData u
GROUP BY u.UId
```

Then join together

```
SELECT *
FROM UserData u
JOIN (
    SELECT u.UId, count(DISTINCT u.Pid) as Uid_property
    FROM UserData u
    GROUP BY u.UId
    ) t1
  ON u.UId = t1.UId
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Pid) as total_properties
    FROM Property
   ) t2
WHERE t1.Uid_property = t2.total_properties
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: This assumes that there will never be a `Pid` value in `UserData` that does not have a corresponding value in `Property` (which could well be correct)

Comment: @MartinParkin I guess you are right, but then I will say db model is wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

This is known as relational division. Query using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT *
FROM Userdata ud1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT pId
          FROM Property p
          WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT 1
                FROM Userdata ud2
                WHERE ud2.UId = ud1.UId
                   AND ud2.pId = p.pId));
```

See more options at
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 0):

this assumes combination of uid,pid is unique in userdata

```
;wITH CTE
AS
(select UId,Pid,OptId,COUNT(PID) OVER (PARTITION BY UID) AS CNT
 from #userdata u
 )
 SELECT UID,PID,OPTID FROM CTE
 WHERE CNT=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PID) FROM #PROPERTY)
```

Comment: why put that restriction? `COUNT(DISTINCT PID)` doesnt work on Partition?

Answer (score 0):

Need to ensure both the data and the count of pid in property.

```
;WITH cte_cntUserdata
 AS
  (SELECT UId,PId,OptId,COUNT(PId) OVER (PARTITION BY UID) AS Cnt_Pid
   FROM Userdata u
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                               FROM Property p 
                               WHERE u.Pid=p.Pid and u.optId=p.optId)
                                )
  SELECT UId,PId,OptId 
  FROM cte_cntUserData 
  WHERE Cnt_Pid=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PId) FROM Property)
```